# Why is Node.js installation unpacking some Python packages?

Tags: python, node.js

.. such as the ones in following screenshot (Node 8 on Ubuntu):

[image: node.js installation python packages]

Comment: True. Thanks Jared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know a Node package does not only have to consist of only JavaScript. It could require `python` or contain `C`.

CasperJS even contains `C#`:

https://github.com/casperjs/casperjs/blob/master/src/casperjs.cs

NodeJS itself uses `gyp` so naturally I would assume it also requires python if it is not already present on your machine:
https://nodejs.org/en/docs/meta/topics/dependencies/#gyp

Comment: OP is talking about node itself, not a package, and *most* of node is written in C++.

Comment: I am not installing any specific package, just a "default" Node 8.12 installation.

Comment: it uses `gyp` which is a python package, so it needs python: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/meta/topics/dependencies/#gyp